# The code doesn't compile on remix.ethereum.org

Tags: tokens

The error is:

> browser/ballot.sol:54:2: ParserError: Function, variable, struct or
> modifier declaration expected.
>
> }

The code of my token:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

interface Token{
   function transfer(address _receiver, uint256 _amount);
}

  contract MyFirstSafeICO{

 uint public buyPrice;

 Token public token;

 function MyFirstSafeICO(Token _token) {

    token = _token;  
    buyPrice = 1000;
}

 function() payable {
  
     _buy( msg.sender, msg.value);
 }

 function buy() payable returns (uint ){

  uint tokens = _buy(msg.sender, msg.value);
  return tokens;
}

 function buy(address _sender, uint256 _amount) internal returns (uint){

 uint tokens = _amount/buyPrice;

  token.transfer( _sender, tokens);

  return tokens;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax 2 error's,

1. _buy() definition not found
2. didn't closed contract.

I am attaching modified code:
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

```
interface Token{
   function transfer(address _receiver, uint256 _amount);
}

  contract MyFirstSafeICO{

 uint public buyPrice;

 Token public token;

 function MyFirstSafeICO(Token _token) {

    token = _token;  
    buyPrice = 1000;
}

 function() payable {

     _buy( msg.sender, msg.value);
 }

 function buy() payable returns (uint ){

  uint tokens = _buy(msg.sender, msg.value);
  return tokens;
}

 function _buy(address _sender, uint256 _amount) internal returns (uint){

 uint tokens = _amount/buyPrice;

  token.transfer( _sender, tokens);

  return tokens;
 }
}
```

Comment: @Anatoly let me any issues

Answer (score 1):

That error is because you're missing a closing curly brace at the very end of your code.

Then you'll see errors because you're trying to call a function called `_buy`, but you don't have any function with that name. You do, however have *two* functions named `buy`. I think you probably meant the second one to be named `_buy`, so just change its name.

At that point, the code compiles.